# How to convert CorelDraw .WI wavelet-compressed image

Tags: image-processing, file-format, file-conversion, wavelet, coreldraw

I have a large sample of .WI images I need to convert to e.g. JPEGs, but the format now seems defunct.

The mimetype is image/wavelet.

The compression algorithm was developed by Summus, a US company that also now seems defunct.

The last CorelDraw support for the format was under 32-bit Windows. If I go down the hardware route I need to be able to make calls to a server via e.g. REST.

I think under *nix djvulibre might be able to open the files, but I haven't been able to test this yet.

Another option is to re-implement the codec myself.

It would be a nice-have to be able to script this.

Here's an example file http://www.wolfgang-rolke.de/graphics/wavelet.wi

Comment: Maybe make a 32-bit virtual machine in VirtualBox, grab a copy of Windows and an old copy of CorelDraw from eBay, load it up, convert the lot and archive your VM.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! It would be nice to script it... Sorry for not saying (will update)

Comment: @jtlz2 I also have .wi files that I need to convert / decompress to .bmp, CorelDraw in 32 bit Windows can import .wi files and save them as .bmp. Do you know where I can find this Summus algorithm?

Comment: @langjacques Might be able to help - what is your use case?

Comment: @jtlz2 I need to decompress an image (.wi) byte array that is scanned from a South African driving license barcode, I am able to decrypt the barcode but the photo data is compressed

Comment: @langjacques My company now offers an API to do that very thing (see https://sprinthive.com/#advanced_kyc). Get in touch with me if you are interested.

Comment: @jtlz2 did you solve this? Please write an answer describing the solution, to help others.